# Optimize the query of fetching latitude and longitude values from Geometric Column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table which contains a column location with Geometry Data Type.
I am running a query to fetch the value of latitude and longitude from geometry column which takes about 21 seconds to execute on about 3.83 lac records.

Query is :

```
SELECT location.STY as Lat, location.STX as Lon from myTable;
```

Is there any method to optimize this query , which can reduce the execution time of this query.

Answer (score 1):

You may add filtering else based on your sample query your extacting all the record
see below.

```
SELECT location.STY as Lat, location.STX as Lon from myTable where location.STY between [a] and [b]
```

And also create an index for location.STY and/or location.STX

Comment: If you do have 1 million records and you don't specify a where clause for filtering then what you are doing is retrieving all 1 million record.. And you know what will be the consequence.

Comment: actually I have applied the filtering and getting 3.83 lac records after it